# When to programmatically check for theme changes in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I have a page in a Windows Phone 8.1 app where I have a few components that should be able to have three different color states. They should either be red, blue or the current theme's foreground color.

Therefore, if my app is started using the Dark theme on the phone, and then the user steps out of the app and changes the Light theme, and steps in to my app again, I need to immediately change components that had the old theme's foreground color.

Since the components are supposed to change between different colors (where the theme's foreground color is just one of them) I can't set their Foreground to `PhoneForegroundColor` in `XAML`.

What I've done is to add a `Resuming` event listener that does this:

```
myTextBlock.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush((Color)Application.Current.Resources["PhoneForegroundColor"]);
```

But... the `Resuming` event is fired before the resources of Application.Current are updated, so I end up with the same color as before. If the user steps out again and in again, it'll work since `Application.Current.Resources["PhoneForegroundColor"]` was updated at some point after the `Resuming` event the previous time.

**Question:** When can I first read the updated `Application.Current.Resources["PhoneForegroundColor"]`, since `Resuming` doesn't seem to be the right place?

**Question:** Alternatively, is there a way for `myTextBlock` to inherit another component's ForegroundColor (CSS-ish), so that I can change the `myTextBlock.Foreground` programatically between Red/Blue/Inherit without having to mind changes to the Phone Theme within my app's lifecycle?

Any suggestions appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Regarding your first question:** The "Resume process" isn't officially documented, but I figured out the following:

Resume gets called on the UI thread. As it is a void returning method, the caller will just continue, when it has an await inside. If you marshall something into the UI thread, it will be in the dispatcher queue and therefor run after the current task (resume).

So I just made this (and it works^^):

```
private async void App_Resuming(object sender, object e)
{

    var x1 = new SolidColorBrush((Color)Application.Current.Resources["PhoneForegroundColor"]);
    Debug.WriteLine(x1?.Color.ToString());

    // Await marshalls back to the ui thread,
    // so it gets put into the dispatcher queue
    // and is run after the resuming has finished.
    await Task.Delay(1);

    var x2 = new SolidColorBrush((Color)Application.Current.Resources["PhoneForegroundColor"]);
    Debug.WriteLine(x2?.Color.ToString());
}
```

---

**Regarding your second question:** You could introduce a "ValueProvider" in your app.xaml, that registers for the resume event and just provides a dependency property with the current color.

You will still have to set that on any TextBlock you want to use that in, but at least directly in XAML. This might work for styles too, but did not try that.

Sample implementation....

Provider:

```
public class ColorBindingProvider : DependencyObject
{
    public ColorBindingProvider()
    {
        App.Current.Resuming += App_Resuming;
    }

    private async void App_Resuming(object sender, object e)
    {
        // Delay 1ms (see answer to your first question)
        await Task.Delay(1);

        TextColor = new SolidColorBrush((Color)Application.Current.Resources["PhoneForegroundColor"]);
    }

    public Brush TextColor
    {
        get { return (Brush)GetValue(TextColorProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextColorProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextColorProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("TextColor", typeof(Brush), typeof(ColorBindingProvider), new PropertyMetadata(null));
}
```

App.xaml:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <local:ColorBindingProvider x:Name="ColorBindingProvider" TextColor="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}" />
</Application.Resources>
```

MainPage.xaml:

```
<TextBlock Text="Hey ho let's go" Foreground="{Binding TextColor, Source={StaticResource ColorBindingProvider}}" />
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I also got the first one to work so I'm going with that solution:) For the alternative solution though, I would need to programmatically set the Foreground to "{Binding TextColor, Source={StaticResource ColorBindingProvider}}" right? Since I might have overwritten it with Red or Blue, so whatever was in the XAML is not active anymore...

Comment: No, you can just put your Color setting in the "App_Resuming" method of the provider. It is a dependency property, so it will notify all bindings on update. You of course have to trigger it somehow, if you change the color settings on runtime. Use messaging, or just get the provider via App.Current.Resources[...] and set the property.

Comment: Btw: Instead of using a dependency property, you could also just have the BindingProvider implement INotifyPropertyChanged...

Answer (score 1):

In Windows Phone 8.1 you are able to determine the selected theme via `Application.Current.RequestedTheme` witch will return a value of the enum `Windows.UI.Xaml.ApplicationTheme`.

example:

```
public static string GetImagePath(){
    // if the background color is black, i want a white image
    if(Application.Current.RequestedTheme == ApplicationTheme.Dark)
        return "ms-appx:///Assets/img_light.jpg";

    // if the background color is white, i want a dark image
    return "ms-appx:///Assets/img_dark.jpg";
}
```

side note: you are even able to change the selected theme with `Application.Current.RequestedTheme`

more details: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.application.requestedtheme

Answer (score 0):

Register to App_Resuming didn't work for me because this event isn't raised when application is not suspended. I had to listen to `Window.Current.CoreWindow.VisibilityChanged += CoreWindow_VisibilityChanged;`

No need for `Task.Delay` with this solution.